# Vue.js dynamic image src with webpack require() not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to bind image src dynamically to a URL of the form `../assets/project_screens/image_name.jpg`.

My directory structure looks like:

```
- src
 -- assets
   ---- project_screens
 -- profile
   ---- ProjectList.vue 
 -- store
   ---- profile.js
```

I know that I need to use webpack's `require("path/to/image")` to help webpack build those images, but the path doesn't resolve.

```js
// store/profile.js
projects = [
  {
    ....
  },
  {
    ....
    img_url: "../assets/project_screens/im1.jpg"
    ....
  }
  ....
]
```

```js
// profile/ProjectList.vue
<md-card
   class="md-layout-item project-card"
   v-for="(project, idx) in projects"
   :key="idx"
 >
    <md-card-media>
        <img :src="require(project.img_url)" alt="People" />
    </md-card-media>
</md-card>
```

If I used a URL string instead of dynamically passing the URL string it works. Looked around stack overflow and none of the solutions helped. Am I missing something else ?

Comment: I just use a method() in src attribute that calls a nodejs function that reads and responses it's contents. Works like a charm.

Comment: please try to reproduce your issue based on [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-examples-m1zgo)

Comment: Made a little demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-examples-7crvi in App.vue but it gives a different error that "file_name hasn't been transpiled yet" where as it errored out "Cannot find module '../assets/project_screens/image.jpg'" when I ran locally..!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I finally figured it out!! Webpack cannot import the file if its name is completely given as a variable like:

```
require(imageUrl) // doesn't work
```

This is because it doesn't know the path at compile time if the path is stored in a variable.

But Webpack can detect files to bundle when it is given a string interpolation in require() like:

```
require(`../assets/profile_screens/${filename}`) // Works
```

This works because Webpack knows the path "../assets/profile_screens" at compile time so it can include all the files inside the folder.

Comment: You could also use `require()` in your `projects` array definition as opposed to within your template

Comment: Sure @Phil, but if I move to a database later I need to refactor them again right?

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! I was struggling with issues all morning using require() in a vue project, and it was when I finally saw this answer that it dawned on me, of course a variable wouldn't work because it's doing the processing at compile-time!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax below worked for me:

```html
<img :src="`${project.img_url}`" alt="People" />
```

It works with full url.

`require()` not required.