# Vue Navigation Guard redirects when accessing URL directly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set up [Vue Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). One of my guards redirects users from the `Index` component to the `Dashboard` component if they are authenticated with Firebase Auth.

It works fine if I navigate to the `Index` page via a router link from another component. However, if I go to the `Index` page by directly typing the URL in my browser, it does not correctly redirect the user.

How can I achieve this redirect regardless of how the user accesses the route?

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Index',
    component: () => import('../components/Index.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: () => import('../components/Dashboard.vue')
  }
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser
  if(isAuthenticated && to.path === '/') {
    console.log(to.path);
    next('/dashboard')
  }
})
```

I have also tried `beforeRouteEnter` on the individually defined route, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js dynamic image src with webpack require() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349167/vue-js-dynamic-image-src-with-webpack-require-not-working)

Comment: No, that's a completely different issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your navigation guard gets called before you get user data from firebase. At this point firebase.auth().currentUser is null just as if you are not authenticated.

Check out [this solution](https://dev.to/gautemeekolsen/vue-guard-routes-with-firebase-authentication-f4l). It's very elegant and solves your problem.